# Uncaught lua script exception LuaRT Studio v1.1.1 and v1.3.2.x64 Windows 10 x64 bit

Tags: lua, ide

Since I was learning lua in LuaRT 1.1.1, it was working fine until I closed the LuaIDE then put my laptop to sleep and after I woke it up, I tried *running* the application then it showed me this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6q0r.jpg)

I tried installing newer version to solve it, so that the error is resolved but it didn't

Comment: Yes it's a known bug, fixed in latest development branch (not yet available in binary release). See https://github.com/samyeyo/LuaRT-Studio/issues/16